# Наиболее оптимизированный поиск вывода id

Tags: javascript

Какой способ лучше подойдет для вывода наименования id,

через поиск элементов или напрямую без поиска элементов?

Какой способ более оптимизированный?

```js
let find = document.querySelector('#main')

alert(`first id name: ${find.id}`);   // Вывод id через поиск 

alert(`second id name: ${home.id}`);  // Вывод id напрямую без поиска
```

```html
<div id="main">
<div id="home">
Text
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: А самостоятельно потестить, не вариант? Создать пару миллионов элементов и подергать их в цикле сотню-тысячу раз из начала, середины и конца списка разными методами. Вычесть из времени окончания процесса время его начала.

Comment: Я бы и с радостью, но мне не хватит знаний, чтобы реализовать это(
Думал, может здесь есть те, которые прошли через это.

Comment: Date.now(), for(){}, .createElemernt(), .appendChild, 2 ваших метода и я бы еще проверил $('#id') и .getElementById()  для полноты эксперимента.

Если не подводит интуиция, то getElementById должно быть самым быстрым, но ХЗ...

Comment: А если у меня вместо id будут классы, тогда лучше использовать querySelector ?

Comment: Вот проверьте и будете знать. )) Алгоритм я вам в самом первом комменте написал, список ф-ци1 в предыдущем. Как вывести результат измерений, думаю, придумаете/нагуглите.